# QGIS print composer layout with several data frames: is it possible?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, data-frame

I have to create a several data frame print composer layout: is there a command or a plugin in QGIS 2.4.0 Chugiak that allows to insert several data frame? I dont't know if QGIS can manage more than one data frame (maybe I'm talking with an ESRI language referring to "data frame").